# Joining two tables in asp.net webapi 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Need help joining two table in asp.net webapi 2

I have the following code to join two table

```
  public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {


        var q = (from n in db.Employees
                 join c in db.tblCities on n.ProjectID equals c.CityID

                 select new
                 {
                     n.Name,
                     n.Email,
                     c.CityName,

                 }).ToList();
        return q;

    }
```

but i get this error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List<>' to
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a
>   cast?)    WebApplication15    C:\Users\admin\source\repos\WebApplication15\WebApplication15\Controllers\EmployeesController.cs    35  Active

employee model

```
namespace WebApplication15
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class DtscEmployee
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ProjectID { get; set; }
        public string ManagerName { get; set; }
        public string ProfileImage { get; set; }

    }
}
```

city model

```
namespace WebApplication15
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class tblCity
    {
        public int CityID { get; set; }
        public string CityName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the return type of your function

Comment: Post the complete function. Most probably the function return type is IQueryable<T> but you are returning q (which is of type Generic List<>)

Comment: it is because the return type is different from `list` type . What is the function return type?

Comment: @Thangadurai updated the code

Comment: Remove `.ToList();` from query to return `IQueryable`

Comment: @user1672994 tried that but no luck, i replaced `var q` by `IQueryable<Employee> q` and removed `.ToList();`

Comment: Try using `.ToList().AsQueryable();`

Comment: @BPDESILVA i tried that as ` IQueryable<Employee> q = (from n in db.Employees` and at the end replaced .ToList(); to ToList().AsQueryable(); return q;

Comment: Removing ToList() will not help you. You need understand the code to find the issue. Your select new creates an anonymous object and it is no more your `employee` so you can't return it. Now, why do you want to join Employee with city table. Remember you are working with Objects and not with SQL tables. So,if your model is designed in such a way that it has navigation properties to its child, then you just need to return only 'Employee'. If you are new to EF, please read a lot

Comment: What value do you receive in `q`?

Comment: @RahulSharma `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<<anonymous type: string Name, string Email, string CityName>>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<WebApplication15.Employee>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) WebApplication15 C:\Users\admin\source\repos\WebApplication15\WebApplication15\Controllers\EmployeesController.cs 24 Active
`

Comment: @Kuku Please show us your context class. What do `db.Employees` and `db.tblCities` look like? Also please show your `Employee` class which you are populating based on your joins

Comment: @RahulSharma updating

Comment: @RahulSharma update my question added the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's take this one step at a time starting with your initial code.

IQueryable is an expression that you are building, a query if you want. That's an important distinction, it's not actual data. You can chain multiple conditions on it, this is why returning an IQueryable is sometimes good as it allows this chaining to happen.

When you are ready to execute the expression and get the actual data, this is when you enumerate, so your ToList() at the end will go and run the query, return the data in the format that you expect, List, not IQueryable

Of course, a clear message at this point becomes that your API endpoint should never return IQueryable as that is not data yet.

So, your code would become something like:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetEmployees()
    {
        var query = (from n in db.Employees
                 join c in db.tblCities on n.ProjectID equals c.CityID

                 select new
                 {
                     n.Name,
                     n.Email,
                     c.CityName
                 });

       var employees = query.ToList();

       //some other things, maybe you want to return BadRequest if there are none or NotFound or whatever you deem appropriate
       return Ok(employees);           
    }
```

a good reading on this is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results

if I were you, I would start simple, get the demo controller in, make sure you can hit the default actions, then modify it with your own ones, take care of the routes, make sure those work properly.

Comment: Thank you so much that worked fine but i cant access api anymore from here http://localhost:50511/api/employees

Comment: i get `The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.` when trying to open api